# Expectation value of Number operator in eigenstates of Hamiltonian involving creation and anihilation operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, quantum-optics, linear-algebra

I wish to estimate the expectation value of the number operator : $$\langle \hat{N} \rangle =\langle \hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{a} \rangle$$

I know the Hamiltonian operator of my system, and thus want the expectation value of this operator when taken between eigenstates of the Hamiltonian.

The Hamiltonian reads : $$\hat{H}=E_0 \hat{I_d} + i E_1 (\hat{a}^{\dagger}+\hat{a}) + E_2 (\hat{a}^{\dagger}+\hat{a})^2 $$
Or equivalently :
$$\hat{H}=E_0 \hat{I_d} + i E_1 (\hat{a}^{\dagger}+\hat{a}) + E_2 ({\hat{a}^{\dagger}}^2+\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}+\hat{a}\hat{a}^{\dagger}+{\hat{a}}^2)$$

Where $\hat{I_d}$ is the identity operator, $\hat{a}^{\dagger}$ and $\hat{a}$ are respectively creation and anihilation operators, and where $E_0$,$E_1$ and $E_2$ are real numbers.

How would I go about finding the eigenstates $\vert \Psi_i \rangle$ of $\hat{H}$ ?

In order to then compute the expectation value of $\hat{N}$ when the system is in an eigenstate of $\hat{H}$:
$$\frac{\langle \Psi_i \vert \hat{N} \vert \Psi_i \rangle}{\langle \Psi_i \vert\Psi_i \rangle}$$

Comment: Your question title compared to the body of the question is very confusing. You want to get the eigenstates of $H$ - as far as I can see, *this* is the question. What you do with the eigenstate then is up to you...

Comment: Your Hamiltonian is not Hermitian (unless $E_1$ is purely imaginary). Are you sure about that factor of $i$? -- or perhaps you mean $\hat{a}-\hat{a}^{\dagger}$ in that term. In any case, to diagonalize $\hat{H}$, you'll need a [Bogoliubov transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogoliubov_transformation).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ladder operator identity for $\langle n | (a+a^\dagger)^k | m \rangle$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/386221/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Hamiltonian reads : $$\hat{H}=E_0 \hat{I_d} + i E_1 (\hat{a}^{\dagger}+\hat{a}) + E_2 (\hat{a}^{\dagger}+\hat{a})^2 $$
> ...

> How would I go about finding the eigenstates $\vert \Psi_i \rangle$ of $\hat{H}$ ?
>
> In order to then compute the expectation value of $\hat{N}$ when the system is in an eigenstate of $\hat{H}$:
> $$\frac{\langle \Psi_i \vert \hat{N} \vert \Psi_i \rangle}{\langle \Psi_i \vert\Psi_i \rangle}$$

First, it may be helpful to recognize that your Hamiltonian can be written in terms of a position operator $\hat X$ as:
$$
\hat H = \alpha + \beta\hat X + \gamma \hat X^2\;,
$$
since
$$
\hat X \propto \hat a + \hat a^\dagger\;.
$$

Therefore, your Hamiltonian is like a [*shifted* simple harmonic oscillator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/129664/eigenstates-of-a-shifted-harmonic-oscillator), but with no kinetic term.

You can shift the creation operators like:
$$
\hat b = \hat a + \delta\;,
$$
where $\delta$ is a number (not an operator), and where the shift can be chosen to put the Hamiltonian into the form:
$$
\hat H = \epsilon + \zeta (\hat b^\dagger + b)^2
$$
$$
=\epsilon + \eta {\hat Y}^2\;,
$$
where
$$
\hat Y \propto (\hat b + \hat b^\dagger)
$$
where $\epsilon$ and $\zeta$ are numbers.

Therefore, eigenstates of the Hamiltonian are eigenstates of the $\hat Y$ operator, which [can be written in the form](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/312004/position-and-momentum-eigenstates-in-terms-of-creation-and-annihilation-operator):
$$
\left|y\right>\propto e^{\sqrt{2}~yb^\dagger-(b^\dagger)^2/2}\left|0\right>\;.
$$
and where:
$$
\hat H |y\rangle = |y\rangle(\epsilon + \eta y^2)\;.
$$

The expectation value of the number operator is thus:
$$
\langle N\rangle 
=\langle a^\dagger a\rangle 
= \frac{\langle 0 |e^{\sqrt{2}~yb-(b)^2/2} a^\dagger a e^{\sqrt{2}~yb^\dagger-(b^\dagger)^2/2}\left|0\right>}{\langle 0 |e^{\sqrt{2}~yb-(b)^2/2}e^{\sqrt{2}~yb^\dagger-(b^\dagger)^2/2}\left|0\right>}
$$